# Difference between rpm php and php54 packages from remi repo

Tags: php, yum, rpm

I am doing some system automation where we need php 54. We install this from the remi repo.

I can't tell what's different other than size in the two below:

php54-php-common-5.4.32-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm

php-common-5.4.32-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the repo [FAQ](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/English-FAQ):

> **php-* packages are standard ones:**
>
> - they override the default system version (still an admin choice, as    you have to enable the repository to get them)
> - only one version can be installed
> - one repository per version (remi, remi-php55 and remi-php56)
>
> **php54-php-*, php55-php-* and php56-php* packages are Softwares Collections:**
>
> - they can be installed beside the default system version (in    /opt/remi)
> - various versions can be installed simultaneously
> - all the versions are in the remi repository